# Scientifically important discoveries with the help of amateurs

Tags: amateur-observing, supernova, history

I am looking for examples where amateur astronomers in these days contributed sigificantly to important scientifically discoveries.

I am aware of one example: [Victor Buso](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-02331-4?utm_source=twt_nnc&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=naturenews&sf182688358=1) from Argentina was lucky enough to observe a Supernova just when it formed, which has led to follow-up observations by large scientific observatories, and in the end resulted in a [Nature article](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature25151) which has Buso as a co-author.

What might some other similar examples be?

---

**below:** "Astronomer Victor Buso poses in front of the telescope with which he witnessed the birth of the supernova 2016gkg. (Victor Buso)" From [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2018/02/21/a-self-taught-astronomer-spotted-something-no-scientist-had-ever-seen/?utm_term=.48aef0106509), borrowed from [Does this amateur observation hold a record even including robotic searches for supernovae?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25229/7982). Click/open for full size.

[image]

Comment: There should be heaps. Astronomy is considered to be one of the last fields where amateurs can still make important discoveries.

Comment: [14 Space Discoveries By Amateur Astronomers](https://www.rankred.com/space-discoveries-by-amateur-astronomers/),[Great Discoveries by Amateur Astronomers](https://abcnews.go.com/Technology/Space/story?id=8221167&page=1), https://www.google.ca/search?q=amateur+astronomer+discovery

Comment: `+1` I hope you don't mind the edit; feel free to roll back or adjust.

Answer (score 6):

I guess it depends on what you consider *scientifically important*, but users at [Planet Hunters](https://www.zooniverse.org/projects/nora-dot-eisner/planet-hunters-tess/) have helped with the [discovery of several exoplanets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Hunters#Discoveries) by analyzing data from the [Kepler Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_(spacecraft)), as well as the famous [Tabby's star (KIC 8462852)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIC_8462852) which has led to a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.03622) by Tabetha Boyajian co-written by the users who participated in the analysis of the light curve of the star.

The star is currently still the subject of numerous studies and publications.

Answer (score 4):

A quite recent example is [Hanny's Voorwerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanny%27s_Voorwerp), not done though direct observations, but discovered in 2007 by Dutch schoolteacher Hanny van Arkel while she was participating as a volunteer in the [Galaxy Zoo project](http://zoo1.galaxyzoo.org/Project.aspx).

[image]
<sup>(https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hannys_voorwerp.jpg)</sup>