# Is there any way to find out what sky surveys are *currently active?*

Tags: sky-survey

I've asked a [question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25007/7982) about active sky surveys that might intercept a 2% of 4π patch of sky in the next six months and potentially record this dim (+22 to +26 magnitude) object.

I've added a bounty with about one more day on the grace period, the only thing helpful was a comment that suggested I ask for a "database of surveys".

Are there any pages that list at least major active surveys? That would be a start at least.

Comment: On each program website

Comment: @KornpobBhirombhakdi that's not really helpful. I've asked "Are there any **pages that list** at least major active surveys? That would be a start at least." If you know which programs to check for activity, then that would be a great answer! If you don't, then, we're back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want a list, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_survey#List_of_sky_surveys) has a pretty good page on astronomical surveys.

For some comprehensive information, including some tabulated values (such as sky coverage for each survey), try [this paper from S. G. Djorgovski et al.](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1203/1203.5111.pdf)

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll give these a look. While the lists are long, checking that they are *currently active* should narrow that down quite a bit as these are lists of catalogs, rather than active, ongoing observations in 2018. Of course if these are not actively curated, then they may miss those surveys that have started recently. Part of the problem is of course that the term "survey" can refer to the activity itself, or the resulting body of work.